# Vowel list: weird lambda expression

Tags: python, list, lambda, filter

Could someone explain why the following code produces a list of vowels? It seems as if the lambda expression should only be looking at the first letter of a string, but somehow it is collecting all characters of the string which are in "aeiou":

```
nameFull = input("Please enter your name: ")
nameBroken = nameFull.split()

print(list(filter(lambda x: x[0] in "aeiou", nameFull)))

#(i.e. if nameFull = hello, ["e", "o"] is the result)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing `nameFull` to `filter` will cause each individual character of the string to be sent to the `lambda` as `x`. The `[0]` inside is redundant and not necessary; it just grabs the first character of `x`, which is already a single-character string. You should probably remove it for readability.

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> nameFull = input("Please enter your name: ")
Please enter your name: Robert
>>> 
>>> print(list(filter(lambda x: x in "aeiou", nameFull))) # Works fine without [0].
['o', 'e']
>>>
>>> 'a'[0] # [0] does nothing.
'a'
>>> 'a'[0] == 'a'
True
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Why is it that each individual character of the string will be sent as 'x'? I thought that lambda would take 'x' to be nameFull.

Comment: No, because the second argument to `filter` is always an iterable that will have each one of its elements sent and filtered. Strings are also iterables in Python (their characters are their elements). So the command filters the string as it would any other iterable.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here the `filter` function filters the characters that are vowels

```
filter(lambda x: x[0] in "aeiou", nameFull)
```

Example: `nameFull` = 'hello'

1st step:

```
lambda x:x[0] in "aeiou", 'hello'
```

In this step `x[0]` is `h`. So the condition fails as `h` not in `aeiou`

2nd step:

```
lambda x:x[0] in "aeiou", 'ello'
```

In this step `x[0]` is `e`. So the condition is true as `e` in `aeiou`. It is filtered.

In the same way for other characters in string.

Finally the filtered one is converted into `list`

```
list(filter(lambda x: x[0] in "aeiou", nameFull))
```

Input:

```
hello
```

Output:

['e', 'o']

Comment: @Ryan Stanfield: Do you need any information on any step ?